# Why is my modified XML not saving the modified values?

Tags: xml, powershell

I've modified every StartOrder and StopOrder value inside my XML using a hashtable - which I can see perfectly fine while debugging. Now when I try to save the XML, all of the old values are in there, and none of the new ones.

So, as I said - I modified the values perfectly fine - which I can see in ISE. Although the .Save function pretty much just copies the "old" XML to the "new" XML.

Powershell:

```bsh
$path = Get-Location

$configXML = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter ManageSQLJobs.xml -File -Recurse
$script:xmldoc = New-Object Xml
[xml]$oofXML = Get-Content $configXML.FullName

$jobNames = $oofXML.Configuration.Servers.Server.Jobs.Job |
            select Name, StartOrder, StopOrder

$hashTable = @{
    BackupFullJob=30
    #showing just one job here otherwise there's a lot more
}

foreach ($key in $hashTable.Keys) {
    $message = 'Job name: {0}, value: {1}.' -f $key, $hashTable[$key]
    Write-Output $message

    foreach ($job in $jobNames) {
        echo "Job name: " $job
        echo "Start order: " $startOrder
        echo "Stop order: " $stopOrder

        if ($job.Name -eq $key) {
            $job.StartOrder = $job.StartOrder.Replace($job.StartOrder, $hashTable[$key])
            $job.StopOrder = $job.StopOrder.Replace($job.StopOrder, $hashTable[$key])
        }
    }
}

$job.Name
$job.StartOrder
$job.StopOrder

$oofXML.Save("C:\Users\janb\Desktop\NewXML.xml")
```

Sample XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration>
  <Description>redacted</Description>
  <Servers>
    <Server Instance="redacted">
      <Jobs>
        <Job Name="BackupFullJob">
          <StartOrder>1</StartOrder>
          <StopOrder>1</StopOrder>
          <Enable>1</Enable>
          <Disable>1</Disable>
          <Stop>0</Stop>
          <Start>0</Start>
          <WaitToFinishAtDisable>1</WaitToFinishAtDisable>
          <WaitToFinishAtEnable>0</WaitToFinishAtEnable>
        </Job>
      </Jobs>
    </Server>
  </Servers>
</Configuration>
```

I expect the StartOrder and StopOrder values inside the XML to be updated with the ones from the hashtable, but they stay the same.
While debugging I can see the values being updated, even at the end of the script - however, when I save the XML, the old values stay there and not the new ones.

Comment: this >>> `[xml]$oofXML = Get-Content $configXML.fullname` <<< loads the file into your XML object. this >>> `$oofXML.Save("C:\Users\janb\Desktop\NewXML.xml")` <<< writes the same object to a new file. this >>> `$jobNames = $oofXML [*...snip...*] ` loads PART of the XML object into a $Var. ///// **_at no point do i see anything that puts the new data into your XML object._**

Comment: Am I not updating the values directly as variables on the loaded XML? Because while debugging, I can see on the $job variable, that the Start and Stop order values are updated.

Edit: different job, but still:
https://i.imgur.com/g9NvskI.png

Comment: the line that starts with `$jobNames = ` uses `Select-Object` and a list of properties ... that makes NEW OBJECTS. there is no connection between the two $Vars at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement

```bsh
$jobNames = $oofXML.Configuration.Servers.Server.Jobs.Job |
            select Name, StartOrder, StopOrder
```

creates custom objects from the `<Job>` nodes, which are detached from the XML data structure. The changes you make apply to those objects, but don't go back into the XML data structure.

Remove the `select` statement

```bsh
$jobNames = $oofXML.Configuration.Servers.Server.Jobs.Job
```

and the problem will disappear.